# What does "randomized reductions" in the SVP problem mean?

Tags: cryptography, integer-lattices

The SVP problem in Lattice Cryptography is said to be NP-hard under "randomized reductions". What does the phrase "randomized reductions" mean?

Does it mean the "basis" is randomly transformed? If so, why can we not use LLL(lenstra-lenstra-lovasz) algorithm to get a "more orthogonal" set of basis vectors? And would this reduce the hardness of the SVP problem?

*Excuse the use of colloquialism in "more orthogonal". I hope it doesn't make the question ambiguous*

EDIT:
Source for the definition of the SVP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem

Comment: The phrase "randomized reductions" does not say anything so specific about the problem as to know whether the basis is randomly transformed or not. All it says is that instead of using a deterministic poly-time algorithm to do the reduction to an NP-complete problem (which is what we usually mean), a probabilistic poly-time algorithm is used. If you want a more precise answer, maybe you could provide the source?

Comment: @MishaLavrov added the source to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word reduction is used in the context of algorithmic complexity, as @MishaLavrov correctly pointed out.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(complexity)

The definition of SVP never pointed to a randomized transformation of the lattice basis. But, the SVP problem is indeed easier to solve using a "good" basis (short and orthogonal). This can be verified through a quick glance of the GGH cryptosystem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GGH_encryption_scheme

And among other basis reduction algorithms the LLL can be used to obtain a "good" basis (short and orthogonal)